# Call to a member function productAttribute() on a non-object

Tags: fatal-error

I have set a new custom attribute called actiekorting with a value of 25% on a product. It shows perfectly in detailed product page. But when I'm trying to copy the same line on a different page (overview page of products) I get the following fatal error: Call to a member function productAttribute() on a non-object in etc..

Comment: When you say overview page of products - is this a custom page or the products listing page? (grid/list view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the class this method belongs to hasn't been instantiated.

Make sure the object you're trying to call `productAttribute()` on is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Output`

## Example

```
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');

echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getActiekorting(), 'actiekorting');
```

Comment: Yeah, your code worked! But a little syntax error this worked: 'actiekorting';) with the ) at the end :p

Comment: I have a small question, when setting this between a div, it won't output the value anymore. Any advice on styling these outputs?

Comment: PHP has no influence on the markup, if you "view source" on whatever browser you are using you can see if it is in fact being rendered but is hidden with CSS.

Comment: When I put a div class around it, you can see the class but there is no output. If I use the same kind of code as I did for my image, name attributes from the product page to this(costum homepage) page then I get the fatal error productAttributie on a non-object etc

Comment: `<div><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getActiekorting(), 'actiekorting');</div>` should work if `$_helper` is defined before it.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function productAttribute() on a non-object in /home/users/inhuvftp/inhuur.equiprent.nl/app/design/frontend/default/theme227k/template/catalog/product/new.phtml on line 61  Is what I get?? And other attributes only has <?php echo $_product->getName();?> etc why doesn't this attribute work!?!?

Comment: Varien_Object implements a magic getter and setter. If there isn't a method defined on the class which matches the get `getName()` for example would eventually call `->getData('name')`.

The reason you are still getting the fatal error is you still haven't defined the $_helper. Somewhere near the top of your template add `<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output'); ?>` then where you want to display the attribute value add `<div><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getActiekorting(), 'actiekorting');</div>`

Comment: Hey! Now it works! Thanks! But ofcourse something else will ruin it.. the short_description costum attribute doesn't show now :/ Something with the mage::helper on top of the template?  <div class="desc_grid1"><?php $small_getDescription = strip_tags($_product->getShortDescription());
                        if (strlen($small_getDescription) < 70) echo($small_getDescription);
                        else { echo mb_substr($small_getDescription, 0, 50,'UTF-8').'...';} ?></div>  is the code. never touched it, it always worked. but when using the $_helper = Mage::helper it doesn;t..

Comment: Nevermind, everything is working! You are my hero of the day!