# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function productAttribute() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I have **some products which are displaying on the frontend in category and search** but when I click on the product to see the detail then nothing is shown. Can anyone advise on a process to debug?

**Other products are still showing OK**

- I had a quick look and there doesn't appear to be a difference in setup between the two.
- I'm not receiving an error message there's just no content where the product details should be, the div's however are there.

Here's the error I receive in error log:

> [05-Oct-2015 21:18:34 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function
>   productAttribute() on a non-object in
>   /home/mysite/public_html/app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
>   on line 69

Can anyone help?

Comment: It's specifically the call <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?> that it is having problems with, but as I say only on certain products that do have a title.

Comment: **http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63547/call-to-a-member-function-productattribute-on-a-non-object**
check this out